# Can I configure Backblaze so that it backs up my application folder?

Tags: backup

I would like to configure [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/) so that it backs up the folders `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`. It doesn't seem possible by default:

[image]

The error message I get when clicking on 'delete folder':

[image]

Is there any way around?

Comment: You could try [creating a symbolic link or junction point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) to that folder as e.g. `C:\Programs` and try to backup that.

Comment: Good point, I'll try that.

Comment: Neither worked for me. I eventually used Duplicati to do a local backup which in turn is backup'ed by Backblaze etc.

Comment: @Sev good trick, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way around that. Backblaze, Crashplan, and Carbonite don't allow backups of your systems actual OS/Programs.  So since you can't create an actual system image with this type of backup software backing up your program folders wouldn't provide any real benefits for most programs.

Also backing up folders like C:\windows really doesn't do any good either for the same reason listed above. Backblaze is really just meant to backup files like, movies, pictures, documents etc. It's not intended for creating bootable system images and or sys state information.

If you're simply wanting to create a system image so you have a backup of your actual system you should use windows built in imaging tool. Go to start, type "backup and restore" and then click on "backup and restore" then to the left you'll want to click "create a system image" this will allow you to create a actual bootable system image you can use for restoring your actual system state such as settings/programs/files etc. Backblaze cannot create a bootable system image. (Although you can use it to backup the Windows image backup.)

Comment: Thanks, did you try the Daniel Beck's idea (creating a symbolic link or junction point)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a backup utility like [Duplicati](https://www.duplicati.com/) to create a backup job that backups to another local folder that Backblaze won't exclude.

Downside is that you will use twice the size of the original folders, but you can be selective on what is backed-up if you prefer.